# Margins & Images Issue

Tags: html, css, margin

for the life of me, i can't figure out why the margins won't render properly on some of the images here. After the first and second landscape orientation images, the margins overlap with the image/container above it.

Can anyone shed some light?

http://jsfiddle.net/JeffPannone/rDw6R/17/

*sorry everyone. I provided the wrong jsfiddle link previously. i corrected it here

Answer (score 4):

One option is to set `overflow:auto` to the div.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rDw6R/9/)**

Comment: I knew `overflow:hidden` was useful on keeping floating elements in. I will start using this instead of the padding fix. +1

Comment: I did know about that fix, however, I linked the wrong jsfiddle example. I corrected it in the original post.

Comment: @j08691 - yep. it seems i made a mistake in the css. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The margin of you images can [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) out of the div because you div has no border or padding.

I was adding some W3C documentation, but it's a bit much to give you a clear description of margin collapse in a few lines. Just follow the link above for detailed information.

A simple fix would be adding a padding of `1px 0` to the div.

http://jsfiddle.net/rDw6R/1/

Comment: I did know about that fix, however, I linked the wrong jsfiddle example. I corrected it in the original post.