# Is setting overflow: auto to all elements except html bad practice?

Tags: html, css, overflow

When it comes to starting a new design I always start my style sheet with overruling the browser's default padding and margin on all elements:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

After reading [j08691's answer on a margin collapse problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12412985/880619) I realized `overflow: auto` fixed more than I knew of. I was wondering if it would useful to add  `overflow: auto` on all elements inside the `html` (you don't want to loose the scroll-bar there). So:

```
html * { overflow: auto; }
```

I tried adding this rule to one of our sites, and at first glance this works well, but I'm afraid it might break the more exotic elements (that I'm not using now, but might later) and ... Internet Explorer.

Do any of you have experience with a default `overflow: auto`? Is it a bad thing to do? Should I opt for a milder version and defining a default `overflow: auto` only on `div` elements?

Comment: An `overflow` that isn't the default `visible` potentially breaks floats, margin collapse (which really isn't always a bad thing), and a number of other formatting bits and pieces. If you set it across all elements I can imagine several issues cropping up. I'd rather not do it.

Comment: Hmm.. you don't want to break margins on headings, paragraphs etc.. I think the milder div version (`div { overflow: auto; }`) is a better idea then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I do think it's bad practice. You should only use it when you don't know whether the content can break the size of an element.

Comment: Well, you can always add exceptions.

Comment: Using it on `html *` would lead to too many exceptions... I know.