# Would there be a downside to setting my base <div> style to include “overflow:auto”?

Tags: html, css

I kept running into issues where a child div’s content would expand beyond its parent container. This was solved (using an answer I found on here) by setting the parent container’s overflow to “auto”.

My question is basically the subject line above: would there be a downside to setting my base/global  style to include “overflow:auto” as the default? Since this simple addition seems to make parent containers properly *contain* their floating children, would in not make sense to default to that for everything and just change it when needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for fun, I added `*{overflow:auto}` to this page. Here's what it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/OxWKq.png

Comment: Hmm… Thanks for that. I see how the children randomly resize too.

Comment: possible near-duplicate of [Is setting overflow: auto to all elements except html bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413767/is-setting-overflow-auto-to-all-elements-except-html-bad-practice)

Comment: It wouldn't make sense, because you're using it for something it was never intended for. And as demonstrated in @Pumbaa80's screenshot, it has all kinds of crazy side effects that you really don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could end up having a scroll running across the bottom of the site or "specific divs" you have set overflow: auto.

Reading what you said about nested float divs not showing correctly;
This is because when you set a div to "float" you remove it from the natural flow of the site.
Have you tried fixing the float problem by setting the container div to `clear:both/left/right`?
this would clear the floated divs and set the natural flow back?
This could be your problem.

Comment: The container is already set to “clear:both” because of a series of floating divs immediately preceding it, so I needed something more than just that. Setting overflow to auto did the trick but I hadn’t ever tried it on a child div before, so I was unaware of how they’d react. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With auto, if overflow is clipped due to box constraints, you'll get a scroll bar. You could end up with random scroll bars here and there. inherit is the default, stick with that.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. The info about the box constraints and scroll bars makes perfect sense now. Thanks, @Pumbaa80 for the clarification.